# Using for and if to alter specific data using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data set that has 3 columns - longitude, latitude and data - and 64800 rows.

```
Lon         Lat        Data
-180.0      -90.0      0.0

-180.0      -89.0      1500.0

-180.0      -88.0      18.5
```

etc...

I want to edit the data column in certain geographical areas, e.g. when longitude is between -30 and 70, and latitude between 35 and 70.

I tried to do this pretty simply using a for loop and if statement (code below), with an action when the condition is fulfilled.

```
for myline in infile:
    mylon = f[:,0]
    mylat = f[:,1]
    mydata = f[:,2]
    if (0 < myLon < 30) and (30 < myLat < 50):
        mydata = mydata*1.2
```

But then got this error;

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I'm now using np.logical_and and .all() to deal with the arrays, but now when I use '.all()' the condition isn't applied to the data. If I try '.any()' the action is simply applied to all data rather than just that matching the conditions in the other two columns. I'm not getting any errors.

Any ideas as to what I've missed or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Full code below.

```
import numpy as np

filepath = 'filepath'
filen = filepath+'infile'
f = np.loadtxt(filen,skiprows=1)

outfile = 'outfile'

for myline in infile:
    mylon = f[:,0]
    mylat = f[:,1]
    mydata = f[:,2]
    if (np.logical_and((-30<mylon),(mylon<70)).all()) and (np.logical_and((35<mylat),(mylat<70)).all()):
        mydata = mydata*1.2


np.savetxt(outfile,np.c_[mylon,mylat,mydata], fmt='%13.3f'*2+'%16.2f')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f = np.array([[-180., -90., 0.], [-180., -89., 1500.], [-180., -88., 18.5]])

lon_rng = (-181 < f[:, 0]) & (f[:, 0] < -179)

lat_rng = (-90 < f[:, 1]) & (f[:, 1] < -88)

f[lat_rng & lon_rng, 2] = f[lat_rng & lon_rng, 2] * 1.2

f

array([[ -180. ,   -90. ,     0. ],
       [ -180. ,   -89. ,  1800. ],
       [ -180. ,   -88. ,    18.5]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Wouldn't never have thought to do it like that but it works perfectly.